# Combinatorics related plane geometry

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, integer-sequences

There are $n$ men, standing one at each vertex of a convex $n$-gon. If they are allowed to move together along sides or diagonals of the polygon to reach another vertex, how many different ways are there to do so without meeting another one?

See OEIS [A350599](http://oeis.org/search?q=A350599) for the first few numerical values.

Comment: By "not meeting each other," do you mean that their paths may not cross? Is a man allowed to stand still, or does every man move to a new vertex?

Comment: Probably a question better suited for math.stackexchange than mathoverflow, but in its current form it would be closed there in the blink of an eye. You'll want to read up on how to write a good question on that site before posting it there. Meanwhile, can you solve it for, say, $n=3,4,5$ and look for a pattern?

Comment: This problem looks okay to me. It is stated a little unclearly, but one can guess what is intended.

Comment: Actually I'm unable to guess the meaning of the question (what is meant by a "way to move"?...).

Comment: @YCor intention is to find how many different ways are there for all to move simultaneously to another vertex without meeting another one. Here you need to form nonintersecting closed loops ( polygons). There are real life applications other than what I have mentioned here.

Comment: The linked OEIS page gives a formula, dated from two months ago, as a hypergeometric sum which isn't WZ-summable and is therefore as close to a closed form as you can get. What more do you want?

Comment: @ Peter Taylor ,  I derived general formula using the formula I derived earlier for partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons. There I used the patterns observed upto 20 - gon case  but sometimes there can be much rigorous different approaches using binomials. That's why I thought to share this issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that the paths may not cross and each man must move.
Label the vertices $1,2,\dots,n$ in clockwise order. Let the man at
vertex $i$ move to vertex $\pi(i)$, so $\pi$ is a permutation of
$1,2,\dots,n$. If we draw an arrow from vertex $i$ to $\pi(i)$, then
we get a disjoint union of noncrossing cycles of length $\geq
3$. We can obtain such cycles by choosing a noncrossing partition of
the vertices with no blocks of size 1 and 2, and then orienting the
boundary of the convex hull of each block in two ways. Thus in
Exercise 5.35(b) of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, we should set
$f(i)=2$ for $i\geq 3$ and $f(1)=f(2)=0$. If the desired answer is
$h(n)$, then by this exercise we have
$$ x+\sum_{n\geq 1}h(n)x^{n+1} = \left( \frac{x}{1+2\sum_{n\geq 3}
    x^n}\right)^{\langle -1\rangle} $$
$$ =  \left( \frac{x(1-x)}{(1+x)(1-2x+2x^2)}\right)^{\langle
  -1\rangle},  $$
where $\langle -1\rangle$ denotes compositional inverse.

If a man is allowed to stand still, replace $1+2\sum_{n\geq 3}x^n$ by
$1+x+2\sum_{n\geq 3}x^n$.

Possibly you can get some kind of explicit formula for $f(n)$ out of
this, but it will be messy.

Comment: Yes as you suggested this is regarding how to form nonintersecting closed loops that means how many different ways are there to partition the set of vertices of a convex n - gon into nonintersecting directed polygons. I tried this as a research and the result published in OEIS A 350599

Comment: R. P. Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics, Wadsworth, Vol. 1, 1986, page 93, problem 7 is cited at https://oeis.org/A000266 which counts "the number of permutations in the symmetric group S_n whose cycle decomposition contains no transposition." This should give the number of ways if men are allowed to stand still.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: where does the noncrossing condition come in?

Comment: The way I read the question, it doesn't say the paths can't cross, it just says no two can be at the same place at the same time. That forces it to be a permutation, and rules out transpositions, but as long as they're careful with their timing it doesn't rule out crossing paths.

Comment: If men are not allowed to stay put, it's https://oeis.org/A038205 derangements with cycle lengths at least three.

Comment: The intended interpretation is that the paths don't cross, as confirmed by OEIS A350599.

Comment: For the case where a man can stand still, we are looking at $$ \left( \frac{x(1-x)}{1-x^2+2x^3}\right)^{\langle -1\rangle} $$ $$ = x(1+x+x^2+3x^3+11x^4+33x^5+97x^6+311x^7+1047x^8+\cdots) $$ not (yet) in OEIS.

Comment: Since speed of the motions not mentioned and no one can meet another one you need to consider nonintersecting partitions.

Comment: Total number of different ways of partitioning the set of vertices of a convex n-gon into nonintersecting polygons is same as what is described in OEIS A 114997 as number of ordered trees with n edges and no unary or binary nodes. But I wanted to find different ways separately when partitioning into 1,2,3,... nonintersecting polygons and I did it upto partitioning into 5 polygons. Thereafter I used the pattern to derive general formula to cover all cases.